# Filtering by find() - Javascript

Tags: javascript, find, httprequest

I am working with my first NodeJS server and I am struggling. Until now I have a GET working perfectly as it is

**WORKING**

```
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  const pageSize = +req.query.pagesize;
  const currentPage = req.query.page;
  const postMode = req.query.mode;
  postQuery = POST.find();
  let fetchedposts;

  if (pageSize && currentPage) {
    postQuery.skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
      .limit(pageSize);
  }
  postQuery.find()
    .then(documents => {
      fetchedposts = documents;
      return post.count();
    }).then(count => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'posts fetched successfully',
        posts: fetchedposts,
        maxposts: count
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Fetching posts failed"
      });
    });
};
```

but now I am trying to add a new parameter to the query, mode. What I am trying to achieve is to filter the list by adding extra attributes to the method `find()`. I have tried to add them like the following code:

**NOT WORKING**

```
exports.getposts = (req, res, next) => {
  const pageSize = +req.query.pagesize;
  const currentPage = req.query.page;
  const postMode = req.query.mode;
  postQuery = POST.find();
  let fetchedposts;

  if (pageSize && currentPage) {
    postQuery.skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
      .limit(pageSize);
  }
  postQuery.find(**(post) => post.private === true**)
    .then(documents => {
      fetchedposts = documents;
      return post.count();
    }).then(count => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'posts fetched successfully',
        posts: fetchedposts,
        maxposts: count
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Fetching posts failed"
      });
    });
};
```

but my server crashed.

**ERROR**

> postQuery.find((post) => post.private === true) TypeError: Cannot read property 'private' of null

How should I do it?

Comment: What is `POST` and shouldn't you do the filtering (getting all the `private` posts) before the pagination (the `skip` and `limit` calls) ?

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried but it fails in the same way

Comment: No, seriously, _what is_ `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that `post` is null at some point. You could probably fix it by checking if it is null before checking the private value:

`(post) => post && post.private === true`